# How to implement line sweep which has been used in van kreveld algorithm in c language for viewshed computation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, gis, geospatial

Earlier I was using this algorithm to compute viewshed from a given point `V`:

1. for a given point `V` go through every point (coordinate) in the grid (calling it a target point `T`).
2. find every coordinate point `p` through which `VT` is passing.
3. if `height(p) < height(V) + |p - V|/|T - V| * (T-V)` then the point `T` is visible from `V`

computing it for every point in the set (by considering them targets T) is daunting task & when I try to compute viewshed for every point then it becomes scary.

I read about line sweep used by van kreveld but I didn't understand and have no idea how to proceed & please suggest me appropriate data structure for storing the data (DEM), its processing and storing the processed data. I am a novice programmer, please help me.

PS: if you have some better approach/algorithm then please share it and put this poor man out of this misery.

Comment: Interesting question, and, yes, easy to see how the algorithmic run time of this in the naive case on a non-trivial sized DEM would be horrific. I found an interesting paper here: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/publications/andrade_geoinformatica.pdf and there is an article on gis.stackexchange.com, here, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37128/how-to-implement-viewshed-calculation, though one of the links is broken.

Comment: How large are your data. Would you be prepared to use Postgres/Postgis at all. It has a raster extension, which can be used to store DEMs, so you could potentially use it for storage, and to write results too. You could theoretically use it to calculate the viewshed, though you have asked for C, so apologies if off topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D Data Structure for coordiante storage in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173515/3d-data-structure-for-coordiante-storage-in-c)

Comment: @Phpdna I assume that was a misclick.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Octree is a data structure for 3d data?

Comment: @John Barca: I can use the previously used algorithm for 20-50 points (or may be more) but I need something for more than 10000 points. BTW thanks for suggesting Postgres/Postgis, I will learn them soon. If you have pseudo code of any algo then please help me with that.

Comment: Not really, sorry. If you look at Grass you will likely find the algorithm in some usable form.

Comment: @Phpdna. I think David is referring to the fact that your possible duplicate question has been deleted :-)

Comment: @JohnBarça:It doesn't matter and I also posted my answer.

Comment: Something new in 2020 ?